# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1,x(1+\epsilon))}{x\Gamma(x)}=0$.

Tags: special-functions, conjectures

I conjecture that for any $\epsilon>0$, we have

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1,x(1+\epsilon))}{x\Gamma(x)}=0
$$

where $\Gamma(x,a) = \int_a^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t$ denotes the incomplete Gamma function, and $\Gamma(x) = \Gamma(x,0)$ is the Gamma function.

I'm also happy with the weaker conjecture

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\int_{x(1+\epsilon)}^\infty t^{x-1}\log(1+t)e^{-t} \mathrm{d}t}{x\Gamma(x)}=0
$$

but I doubt that it is any easier. Any clues?

NB: the stronger conjecture is obtained from the weaker conjecture by upper-bounding $\log(1+t)$ by $t$

Answer (score 1):

I have done an equivalent rewriting of this question in terms of random variables in another thread:
[Tail of a sequence of RV](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730405/tail-of-a-sequence-of-rv)

There the question was answered in more generality by user [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [asymptotic expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)

> $$\Gamma(s,z) = z^{s-1}e^{-z} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(s-k)}z^{-k},\quad |z| \to \infty\quad \rm{and}\quad |\!\arg z| < \tfrac{3}{2} \pi. $$

combined with the [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) of the gamma function.