# Tail of a sequence of RV

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-tails

Consider the sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n=1,2,\dotsc}$ where $X_n$ is gamma-distributed with shape $n$ and scale $1/n$ (or equivalently, $2nX_n$ is $\chi^2$-distributed with $2n$ degrees of freedom). That is, $X_n$ has the p.d.f.
$$
p_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{n^n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} e^{-nx} & \text{for $x \geq 0$} \\
0 & \text{for $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we know that the mean and variance are respectively
$$
\mathsf{E}[X_n] = 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \mathsf{var}(X_n) = \frac{1}{n}
$$
so the sequence tends to $1$ in probability. I want to prove that for any positive $\epsilon>0$, when I split the expectation integral as
$$\begin{align}
1 &= \mathsf{E}[X_n] \\
&= \mathsf{E}\left[X_n\middle|X_n \leq 1+\epsilon\right] \mathsf{Pr}\left\{X_n \leq 1+\epsilon\right\}
+ \mathsf{E}\left[X_n\middle|X_n > 1+\epsilon\right] \mathsf{Pr}\left\{X_n > 1+\epsilon\right\} \\
&= \int_0^{1+\epsilon} x p_n(x) \mathrm{d}x + \int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty x p_n(x) \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$
then the first integral tends to $1$ while the second integral tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. The intuition is that there are very few "outliers" as $n \to \infty$ so that the expectation of $X_n$ conditioned on $X_n > 1+\epsilon$ either remains bounded, or at most, goes to infinity *slower* than $\mathsf{Pr}\left\{X_n > 1+\epsilon\right\}$ goes to zero. Note that by Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\mathsf{Pr}\left\{\left|X_n-1\right| > \epsilon \right\} \leq \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}
$$
And if this is true, does it also hold in more generality? Note that $X_n$ can be represented as the mean of $n$ independent unit-mean exponentially distributed variables. Can we thus formulate a more general statement (not limited only to exponentially distributed variables)?

Note: this is a probabilistic rephrasing of the question [Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1,x(1+\epsilon))}{x\Gamma(x)}=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727965/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-frac-gammax1-x1-epsilonx-gammax-0)
which I posted a few days ago, and which remained unanswered so far, perhaps because it was stripped from its physical meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty xp_n(x) \mathrm{d}x=E(X_n;X_n\gt1+\epsilon)\leqslant\sqrt{E(X_n^2)\cdot P(X_n\gt1+\epsilon)}.
$$
By definition,
$$
E(X_n^2)=E(X_n)^2+\mathrm{var}(X_n)=1+\mathrm{var}(X_n).
$$
By Bienaymé-Chebychev inequality,
$$
P(X_n\gt1+\epsilon)\leqslant P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\gt\epsilon)\leqslant\frac{\mathrm{var}(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty xp_n(x) \mathrm{d}x\leqslant u_\epsilon(\mathrm{var}(X_n)),\qquad u_\epsilon(t)=\frac1\epsilon\sqrt{t(1+t)}.
$$
For every $\epsilon\gt0$, $u_\epsilon(t)\to0$ when $t\to0$ hence the result follows.

Comment: A factor $x$ is missing in the integrals written in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the question. Nice trick with Cauchy-Schwarz! I don't quite understand your notation but I got what you meant:
$$
\int_{1+\epsilon}^\infty xp_n(x) \mathrm{d}x = \mathsf{E}[X_n \cdot \mathbb{I}_{[1+\epsilon;+\infty)}(X_n)] = \dots
$$
where $\mathbb{I}_{\mathcal{A}}$ is the indicator function of the set $\mathcal{A}$. That's how I would write it.

Comment: ...And after a while using these you might want to shorten the notation.